# Spring Boot old versions of endpoint

Tags: spring

I have 5 versions of some endpoint. Only V4 and V5 are used currently on the frontend side. What should I do with the V1, V2 and V3 versions? Should I remove them when are not used anywhere?

```
@PutMapping(consumes = "application/json", path = "/v1/announcement/{id:\\d+}")
@PutMapping(consumes = "application/json", path = "/v2/announcement/{id:\\d+}")
@PutMapping(consumes = "application/json", path = "/v3/announcement/{id:\\d+}")
@PutMapping(consumes = "application/json", path = "/v4/announcement/{id:\\d+}")
@PutMapping(consumes = "application/json", path = "/v5/announcement/{id:\\d+}")
```

The code is duplicated, almost the same for all versions (5 services)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle use the Support-Roadmap, I think this is a good concept.

(https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html)

If the version 1-3 is officially declared as end-of-life (EOL) you shoud/must remove them.

Comment: Ok so I should remove not used endpoint versions...

Comment: According to EOL yes.